# Determinant of Kronecker product $D = B⊗A$ is equeal $D=A^kB^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, kronecker-product

Here determinants:
$$
A = \begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & ... & a_{1n}\\
... & ... & ...\\
a_{n1} & ... & a_{nn}\\
\end{vmatrix}
B = \begin{vmatrix}
b_{11} & ... & b_{1k}\\
... & ... & ...\\
b_{k1} & ... & b_{kk}\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
And Kronecker product $D = B⊗A$:
$$
D = \begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}b_{11} & ... & a_{1n}b_{11} & a_{11}b_{12} & ... & a_{1n}b_{12} && ... && a_{11}b_{1} & ... & a_{1n}b_{1k}\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
a_{n1}b_{11} & ... & a_{nn}b_{11} & a_{n1}b_{12} & ... & a_{nn}b_{12} && ... && a_{n1}b_{1k} & ... & a_{nn}b_{1k}\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
a_{11}b_{k1} & ... & a_{1n}b_{k1} & a_{11}b_{k2} & ... & a_{1n}b_{k2} && ... && a_{11}b_{kk} & ... & a_{1n}b_{kk}\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
a_{n1}b_{k1} & ... & a_{nn}b_{k1} & a_{n1}b_{k2} & ... & a_{nn}b_{k2} && ... && a_{n1}b_{kk} & ... & a_{nn}b_{kk}\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Need to proof that:
$$
D = A^kB^n
$$
I tried to separate this by groups with size $(n,n)$ and took out the $A$ from each row of $D$, then using properties of determinant and got: $\det(AD')=\det(A)^k\det(D')$. I can't understand what I shall do next, and not sure that way is right, because this properties can be not right for groups.

Comment: Hint: what are the eigenvalues of $B \otimes A$?

Comment: No information about this.

Comment: @replikeit have you worked through any examples?

Comment: @Chickenmancer for 3x3 and 4x4 matrices, did not help to understand right way.

Comment: Hint 2: if $u,v$ are eigenvectors of $A,B$, then what is $v\otimes u$?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. understood about first hint, eigenvalues $B⊗A$ is each multiply possible pairs of eigenvalues $A$ and $B$. This helped a bit, thanks.

Comment: @replikeit From there, note that the determinant of a matrix is the product of all of its eigenvalues.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks!!! This was helpfull, to be honest, first time heard about this fact about eigenvalues and determinant, looks like my math-course did not come to this point for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hints have given you an efficient way to do this.

But you can get a proof by continuing along the line you have started on.

You've got, as you have observed, that
$$
D=
\det\begin{pmatrix}
Ab_{11}& &\dots & Ab_{1n}\\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
Ab_{n1}& &\dots & Ab_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\det\begin{pmatrix}
A& \\
 &\ddots &\\
& &  A\\
\end{pmatrix}
\det\begin{pmatrix}
Ib_{11}& &\dots & Ib_{1n}\\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
Ib_{n1}& &\dots & Ib_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
If we now permute the rows and columns of the second determinant we'll get
$$
D=\pm
\det\begin{pmatrix}
A& \\
 &\ddots &\\
& &  A\\
\end{pmatrix}
\det\begin{pmatrix}
B& \\
 &\ddots &\\
& &  B\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and we can check that the sign is $+$ by considering the leading term, or some special case.

Comment: Hmm, I tried permute the rows and columns with 2x2 matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix}
2& 3&\\
4& 5&\\
\end{pmatrix}$. I came to this matrix:$\begin{pmatrix}
2& 3& 0& 0&\\
4& 0& 5 & 0\\
0& 2& 0 & 3\\
0& 0& 4 & 5\\
\end{pmatrix}$ Almost what I need, but one digit always outside diag.

Comment: I don't see how you are getting that. If, eg, $n=k=2$ as per your example, and with your $B$ then in the $4\times 4$ matrix I'd relabel the rows and columns from $1,2,3,4$ to $1,3,2,4$ and be home. In flashier language all I am saying is that $I\otimes B$ and $B\otimes I$ are similar under the obvious map.

Comment: Got it, thanks!